# Angular 4: access template element in other component

Tags: angular, templates, components

I'm using Angular 4. I'm trying to access one component's template element inside another component. The only thing I've found that works (illustrated below) is not very 'Angular'.

Component #1 (which contains the template):

```
  @Component({
    template: `...<input type="text" id="txtUserName" />`
```

Component #2 (which is getting the above component's template element value in a click event):

```
  (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('txtUserName')).value;
```

I've found countless snippets on ElementRef, ViewChild, etc., but none of them actually work for getting the template element's value.
Does anyone know of an Angular 4 approach that accomplishes the same thing I'm doing above?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any relation between Component #1 and Component #2.

if both have parent and child relation ship you can access using @ViewChild() or @input

if there is no relation ship than try to access using shared service 
More info https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: As stated here ... the "Angular-y" approach is that a component should *not* be accessing another component's template unless there is a specific relationship between the components. You can instead use a service as suggested here. I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Comment: DeborahK, I don't have enough StackOverflow points to upvote you, but your article is exactly what I needed. Now I'm able to retrieve the template elements' values in the other component via the getter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [FormGroups](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html) in Angular 4.

### Component A

FormGroups allow you to define the form elements as features of the form, and then attach that description to a form.

Inside the Component A constructor

```
 public constructor(build: FormBuilder) {
     this.form = build.group({
         username: build.control('')
     });
 }
```

You can now use that form group in your template.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <component-b></component-b>
</form>
```

If you place your child component inside a `<form>` that is using the FormGroup you can then access the control via dependency injection.

### Component B

You can access the FormGroup via the directive in the constructor like this.

```
public constructor(public formGroupDir: FormGroupDirective) {
}
```

You have to wait until your component is ready to access the username control.

```
public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    let formGroup = this.formGroupDir.form;
    this.control = formGroup.get('username');
}
```

In the child template you can now **bind** the input to the form group control.

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="control"/>
```

You are all set now. Component **A** will receive form change notifications from the child component via the FormGroup events.

Comment: Thank you, ThinkingMedia. DeborahK's answer (above) accomplished exactly what I need. Still, I'll give your solution a go, too, because I want to understand the various ways of sharing data between components.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest working example would be

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef, Input  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'template-component',
  template: `
<ng-template #templateX>
  <div>This is templateX with text: {{myText}}</div>
</ng-template>  
  `
})
export class TemplateComponent {
  @ViewChild('templateX')
  templateXRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Input()
  myText: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
  <template-component #link myText="John Smith">
  </template-component>

  <div>Hello there.</div>

  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="link.templateXRef"></ng-container>  
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
}
```

See more complex example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-in-separate-component).